# How to make a text input field highlight-able

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, highlighting

For some reason, I have to use the arrow keys to navigate the text contained in this box; i.e. I can't click in the middle of the text with the mouse to start typing and I can't highlight the text to delete it. I honestly thought this was standard for all text inputs, so I'm thinking my CSS might be negating something. Any help appreciated:

```
<input type='text' id='password' value='<?php echo $password; ?>' class='user_input' style='display: table-cell; float:left; width=100%'><br /><br />

.user_input{
    background-color: #444;
    color:#bbbbbb;
    border: none;
    padding:3px;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: `width=100%` isn't valid CSS.

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xums7ybw/

Comment: Works fine for me. What browser you running?

Comment: Sounds like you might having side effects from other javascript or css embedded in your page. Try disabling any third party JS files and see if the problem persists.